# Logging PC data into database via Ruby problem

Tags: mysql, ruby

```
require 'os'
require 'socket'    
require 'mysql2'    
require 'etc'    
require 'time'

def getBits    
    return OS.bits.to_s    
end

def getPCName
    return Socket.gethostname
end

def getUser    
    return Etc.getlogin    
end    

info = Hash["SYSBITS " => getBits,"PCN " => getPCName,"USER " => getUser]

for h in info.keys    
    print h.chomp    
end

for b in info.values    
    print b.chomp    
end

connection = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root",:password => "",:database => "ruby")

result = connection.query("INSERT INTO `mydata`(`#{h}`) VALUES ('#{b}')")
```

So the idea here is to make Hash of information returned and then use Hash keys as columns and hash values as rows in mysql query but it doesn't work.
I added separation manually because I can't see any other way.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
_query': Unknown column 'USER ' in 'field list' (Mysql2::Error)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use [placeholder values](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md) and avoid string interpolation that creates [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Why is there a space after USER in `'USER '`?

Comment: can you output the string value of the query before you try to pass it?

Comment: How are the columns named in the database? Are they really all upcase?